# Get subpath up to the first occurrence of a string

Tags: java, directory, path

I have a Path

a//b/c/d/e.json

and a folder 'd'

Is there an elegant way to get the subpath of the Path up to the first occurrence of 'd'? Preferably using inbuilt methods?

so that I get 'a//b/c/d'

Comment: `str.substring(0, str.indexOf('d') + 1)`.

Comment: I would rather not convert to string is there a way to do this via the Paths api?

Comment: You can just walk up the path until `getFilename()` returns `d`.

Comment: What research have you done to try to do this yourself? Did you **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html), to see what methods are available, and if any of them might be useful for this? --- I think that `getNameCount()` and `getName(int index)` looks interesting, don't you? So what have you tried, using these?

Comment: I could but I'm looking for a more elegant way to do it. Would rather not have any boolean logic

Comment: @Andreas Im familiar with those two. Please read the question I'm looking for an elegant way to do it. I would rather not loop through the entire path until I reach the filename, at least not manually

Comment: Well, that's too bad, because that's the only way to get what you want. Before trying to "optimize" or do "elegant" way, you should at least try a way that works. You can always improve the code later.

Comment: I have tried a working way, thats why my question didnt read 'how do I do this'

Comment: Then you should have shown that in the question, so we wouldn't waste time telling you stuff you already know. But ok, I'll answer your question, not that you'll find it very useful.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an elegant way to get the subpath of the Path up to the first occurrence of 'd'?

No, there is no "elegant" way. Just do it the straight way, using a loop.